# Variable scope in Javascropt

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, scope

I'm having problems with variable scope in javascript. I have the following code that works fine except that the value of `this.myUser` becames `undefined` when it goes out of the `.subscribe(...)` block. I don't understand why since it's a class varibale. Here's my code:

```
private myUser: User;

      login(username: string, password: string): User {

          this.http.get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
            .map((response : Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log('data inside', data);
                this.myUser = data;
                console.log('user inside', this.myUser);
              }
            );

          console.log('user outside', this.myUser);

          return this.myUser;

      }
```

And here's the result from console log:
[image: myResult]

I'm using `angular 4` with `bootstrap 4` (but I don't think that has any influence on the issue).
Thanks for any hint.

**Edit**
I red the link below, so I tried to add `promise` to my code to manage async calls. Online tutorials seems all very simple (too simple indeed, included the `Angular` official reference), so I ended up with something like this:

```
this.http.get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
            console.log('data inside', data);
            this.myUser = data.json() as User;
            console.log('user inside', this.myUser);
          })
      .catch(console.log.bind('Error!'));
```

But it doesn't have any effect on the application flow. I'll keep trying, but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you made this changes.

```
private myUser: User;

login(username: string, password: string) = () : User =>  {

  this.http.get(this.loginUrl + '?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
  .map((response : Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data inside', data);
    this.myUser = data;
    console.log('user inside', this.myUser);
  }
  );

  console.log('user outside', this.myUser);

  return this.myUser;
}
```

The caller of the login function will have no scoped object. Using an arrow function in typescript will persist the this/instance using a local variable to reference the containing class of your function.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems to jump completely the `this.http.get(...)` function because it only logs the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the observable is not completed when you hit this line:

```
console.log('user outside', this.myUser);
```

Observables are asynchronous. The subscribe block will only be executed after the AJAX call (`this.http.get`) has succeeded. The `console.log` statement will be executed right after the observable has been created.

Comment: This question is already marked as a possible duplicate, it doesn't need an answer unless you feel it's not a duplicate ;)